# Selecting a Column in R

Tags: r

I imported a dataset with no column headings, and I'm trying to label the columns for convenience. I've used R quite a bit before, so I'm confused as to why this code isn't working:

```
library(mosaic)
`0605WindData` <- read.csv("~/pathnamehere/0605WindData.txt", header=F)
Station = 0605WindData[,1]
Error: unexpected symbol in "Station = 0605WindData"
```

I swear I have experience with R (albeit I'm a bit out of practice), but I seem to be stuck on something pretty simple. I know I've used this select column command before. Suggestions?

Comment: Check and see if `Station <- 0605WindData[,1]` works

Comment: Your variable names should not start with a number.

Comment: @StephLocke If that *does* work then the OP is not telling us a great deal about what he is doing. At the top level there should be no difference between `<-` and `=`. That is not the issue it is the non-standard object name.

Comment: @GavinSimpson ,@Roman True

Comment: Roman: I changed the name of the imported dataset to "WindData0605" and the command works fine. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to quote the object name when subsetting:

```
> `0605WindData` <- data.frame(A = 1:10, B = 1:10)
> `0605WindData`[,1]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

As Roman points out, object names are not supposed to start with a digit. Your `read.csv()` line only worked because you back-tick quoted the object name. You have to continue to quote the object in every line of code now because you used a non-standard name for that object. Save yourself some trouble and change the name of the object you assign the output from `read.csv()` to.

Answer (score 0):

```
    `0605WindData` <- read.csv("~/pathnamehere/0605WindData.txt", header=F)
    Station = 0605WindData[,1]
```

Instead of using quotes for variable start variable name with letter such as

```
     winddata060 <- read.csv("~/pathnamehere/0605WindData.txt", header=F)
```

Now select the required variable name

```
     Station = winddata060[,1]
```